# Commenting HTML code inside javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm developing in react, but I suppose that this question is applicable to any language mixing javascript and HTML.

I would like to know if there's an easy way of commenting HTML code inside a js file

For example inside the return function I usually have something like:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Text 1</Text>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Text 2</Text>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Text 3</Text>
  </View>
);
```

I would be very useful for me to comment Text2
I tried using the HTML comment `<!--   -->`  but it complains about the ! being an unexpected token.

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
SyntaxError: /home/isaac/Projects/AwesomeProject2/App.js: Unexpected token (20:5
```

What is the best way of commenting the HTML code inside javascript files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{/* ... */}` to comment JSX code.
Also most editors support the `Ctrl + /` shortcut to comment out code with the appropriate syntax.

More info: https://wesbos.com/react-jsx-comments

Comment: I tried with `{#  #}` and did not work. But using `{/*   */}` works well. The link you provided also uses `/*  */`, where did you get the `#` as a comment symbol?

Answer (score 0):

In order to comment a line in .jsx files you need to do it like so:

```js
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {/* <Text style={styles.text}>Text 1</Text> */}
    <Text style={styles.text}>Text 2</Text>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Text 3</Text>
  </View>
);
```